# Define a char array by multiplying two values

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have the following code but the compiler returns: `Invalid use of non-static data member 'columns'` while defining the array.

```
int columns = 10;
int rows = 13;
char characters[columns * rows];
```

If I change this to:

```
#define COLS 10;
#define ROWS 13;
int columns = COLS;
int rows = ROWS;
char characters[COLS * ROWS];
```

I get `Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers`.

This only works if I declare my array by manually entering the numbers like so:

```
char characters[10 * 13];
```

...but of course this is redundant; I don't want to define my cols and rows in two places. I was under the impression that preprocessor directives were a simple search/replace by the compiler so I don't understand why `char characters[COLS * ROWS]` doesn't work and this does `char characters[10 * 13]`

What's the proper way of dealing with this?

*PS: I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 with an OpenFrameworks project.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you append `;` to a macro, you get that `;` in the expansion as well.

That is,

```
#define COLS 10;
#define ROWS 13;
char characters[COLS*ROWS];
```

expands to

```
char characters[10;*13;];
```

which won't compile. Discard the semicolons and you are good to go.

```
#define COLS 10
#define ROWS 13
```

Comment: Guess you can read my thoughts, the same answer as mine 30 seconds earlier... +1 and deleting mine =)

Comment: Just a note for the OP and other readers: most compilers have a command line option to output or save a version of the input translation unit *after* the preprocessing stage (e.g. `g++ -E`) - i.e. after `#include`s are injected, `#if`/`#else`/`#endif` code removal, and `#define`d macro use substitutions.  Whenever you have unexpected or inexplicable trouble with some code and you just can't explain it, it may help to look at the post-preprocessed code, to see if any unexpected substitutions took place, and that known substitutions happened as anticipated.

Answer (score 2):

Array dimensions must be constant expressions:

```
const int columns = 10;
const int rows = 13;
char characters[columns * rows];
```

Note the use of `const`.

The one with `#define` doesn't work because of the extra `;`

```
#define COLS 10;
```

should be

```
#define COLS 10
```